# Regex for any four digits except starting with 88 or 89

Tags: regex

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I need to create a regex that will allow any four digits except ones that start with "88" or "89"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
^(?!8[89])[0-9]{4}$
```

[Read more about it](http://regular-expressions.info)

Comment: Does this need to be anchored or could it match in the middle of a line?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following Regex...

```
 (8[\d-[89]]{1}|[\d-[8]]{1}\d)\d{2}
```

Edit:

Explanation:

- Select from two alternatives:

  - 8[\d-[89]]{1} : 8 followed by any digit except 8 and 9
  - [\d-[8]]{1}\d : Any digit except 8 followed by any digit
    And
- \d{2} - Any digit, exactly 2 repetitions

Comment: Your regex doesn't make sense, at least not in the flavors I've seen. Could you explain it and mention which flavor/engine you're using ?

Comment: Added explanation in the answer above. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah I see, you're using the .NET flavor :) You might remove `{1}` since it's redundant.